# Incremental mapreduce for spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mapreduce

I am working on spring data's support for mongoDB using Java. I have to perform tasks that require mapreduce. I tried map reduce and it worked fine.  Later I came to know incremental mapreduce is better. But I'm not able to find any support for incremental mapreduce in the spring data documentation. Can someone help me on this???

I have used

```
Query query = new Query(where("x").ne(new String[] { "a", "b" }));
MapReduceResults<ValueObject> results = mongoOperations.mapReduce(
          query, "jmr1",  "classpath:map.js",  "classpath:reduce.js",
          options().outputCollection("jmr1_out"), ValueObject.class);
```

for mapreduce.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really don't see anything here that supports showing an "incremental mapReduce". So perhaps you should show how you are implementing this. The "Incremental" term is quite often misused by people actually expecting mapReduce to do something that it actually cannot.

Answer (score 1):

In [regular MongoDB syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/#subsequent-incremental-map-reduce), you indicate incremental MapReduce by replacing

```
out: "outCollection"
```

with

```
reduce: "outCollection"
```

In Spring this corresponds to the [outputTypeReduce](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapreduce/MapReduceOptions.html#outputTypeReduce%28%29) option for [MapReduceOptions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapreduce/MapReduceOptions.html).